# Understanding TensorFlow checkpoint loading?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What's contained in a TF checkpoint? Estimators for example store a separate file that contains the `GraphDef` proto and you can basically do a `tf.import_graph_def()`, then create a `tf.train.Saver()` and restore a checkpoint into the graph. Now if you have another `GraphDef` describing a completely different graph that just happens to share the exact same variable names together with matching variable dimensions, will you be able to load the checkpoint into that graph? In other words, is it just a variable name to value mapping or does it assume something else about a graph that would be checked during loading? What if you try to load a checkpoint into a graph that is a subset of the original graph (i.e. tensor dimensions and names match, but some names are missing)?

Answer (score 1):

When do people start reading the documentation (?):
https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models

These are different concepts. You can load just the weights as long as the shapes match. If there is a miss-match you just get:

> Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a
>   mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint.
>   Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on
>   the checkpoint.

However, you can tweak a non-trivial case, where the graph is completely different:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

test_data = np.arange(4).reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)

# a simple graph and everything is fine
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 2, 2, 1])
output = tf.layers.conv2d(input, 3, kernel_size=1, name='test', use_bias=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(output, {input: test_data}))
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print(tf.trainable_variables())

# reset previous elements
tf.reset_default_graph()

# a new graph
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 2, 2, 1])
# and wait: this is complete different but same name and shape
W = tf.get_variable('test/kernel', shape=[1, 1, 1, 3])
# but the graph has different operations
output = input + W

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print(sess.run(output, {input: test_data}))
```

In my case I got:

```
# 1st version (original graph)
[[[[-0.         -0.         -0.        ]
   [-0.08429337 -1.0156475  -0.42691123]]

  [[-0.16858673 -2.031295   -0.85382247]
   [-0.2528801  -3.0469427  -1.2807337 ]]]]
# 2nd version (altered graph)
[[[[-0.08429337 -1.0156475  -0.42691123]
   [ 0.91570663 -0.01564753  0.57308877]]

  [[ 1.9157066   0.98435247  1.5730888 ]
   [ 2.9157066   1.9843525   2.5730886 ]]]]
```