# How do I restore subset of weights in fully connected layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My **goal** is to **train** a network **sequentially** by first training a **subset** of the **weights** and then training **all** weights. Consider the **two architectures** given
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGYh.png)
first starting with "Network 1" which consists of one input scalar z_1, 2 nodes with weights (w_11, w_21) and biases (b_1, b_2) respectively. "Network 2" extends "Network 1" by adding an input node (z_2) and thus also adding one scalar weight to each node (w_12, w_22). In "Network 2", (w_11, w_21) and (b_1, b_2) are initialized by the training result from "Network 1" while (w_12, w_22) are initialized in some other way.

I know how to save and restore subsets of weights (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142780) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51901076/11180209)). The approach described in the links does, however, not work when using fully connected layers like `tf.layers.dense(...)`, it only works when restoring subsets of variables instantiated by `tf.Variable(...)`. I might have to write a custom layer for this, but I am not sure. **How can my goal be achieved?**

To give some context, the script below saves "Network 1"

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def generator(Z,reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("restore"):
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(Z,2,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name='h1')
    return h1

Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
G_sample = generator(Z)
Z_batch = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[1, 1])
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,scope="restore")
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.save(sess, 'test')
    print('restore/h1/bias:0 :', sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("restore/h1/bias:0")))
    print('restore/h1/kernel:0 :', sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("restore/h1/kernel:0")))
```

This gives the output

```
restore/h1/bias:0 : [0. 0.]
restore/h1/kernel:0 : [[-0.7695515  1.2254907]]
```

The script below restores the graph from the script above and extends it with two weights. **NOTE**: When z_dim = 1, the code runs fine (it just restores the same graph as before), but when z_dim = 2 it obviously fails because it doesn't know what weights to restore in layer "h1".

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def generator(Z,reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("restore"):
            h1 = tf.layers.dense(Z,2,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name='h1')
    return h1
Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,2])
G_sample = generator(Z)
z_dim = 2
Z_batch = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[1, z_dim])

reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader('../test/modeltest')
restore_dict = dict()
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    tensor_name = v.name.split(':')[0]
    if reader.has_tensor(tensor_name):
        print('has tensor ', tensor_name)
        restore_dict[tensor_name] = v

print('restore_dict:', restore_dict)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver(restore_dict)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.restore(sess, 'test')
    print('restore/h1/bias:0 :',sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("restore/h1/bias:0")))
    print('restore/h1/kernel:0 :',sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("restore/h1/kernel:0")))
```

I highly appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Considering your goal, have you tried passing only desired variables to optimizer?

Comment: Thank you for your input. At this stage, I do not need to consider optimization since I am simply interested in transferring a subset of the fully connected layer weights from "Network 1" to "Network 2".

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow 2 is coming soon, and it promotes tf.keras as the official high-level API. In fact, `tf.layers` is deprecated in favor of `tf.keras.layers`. Even if you are still using TensorFlow 1, you should use tf.keras, as it makes everything so much easier, and contrary to popular belief, it is very flexible (you can customize absolutely anything, even the training loop).

Here is an example creating a model and then reusing its first layer. You can either just reuse the layer object directly (but then the models actually share that layer, so training model2 will affect model1, and vice versa), or you can just create a new layer and copy its weights.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

X_train, X_test, X_new = np.random.randn(3, 100, 2)
y_train, y_test, y_new = np.random.rand(3, 100, 1)

# Build model 1
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="relu", input_shape=[2])
output1 = keras.layers.Dense(1)
model1 = keras.models.Sequential([hidden1, output1])

# Train model 1
model1.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd")
history = model1.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

# Evaluate and use model 1
score = model1.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
y_pred = model1.predict(X_new)

# Build model 2, sharing the first layer with model 1
hidden2 = hidden1
output2 = keras.layers.Dense(1)
model2 = keras.models.Sequential([hidden2, output2])

# Alternatively, create a new layer and copy its weights
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="relu", input_shape=[2])
output2 = keras.layers.Dense(1)
model2 = keras.models.Sequential([hidden2, output2])
hidden2.set_weights(hidden1.get_weights())
```

If you really absolutely want to stick to old-style TensorFlow, then you can set any variable to any value using the `assign()` operation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(1.0)
v2 = tf.Variable(2.0)
assign_op = v2.assign(v1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print("Before:")
    print("v1 =", sess.run(v1))
    print("v2 =", sess.run(v2))
    print()
    sess.run(assign_op)
    print("After:")
    print("v1 =", sess.run(v1))
    print("v2 =", sess.run(v2))
```

You need to iterate through all the variables you want to copy and create assignment operations for them, perhaps group them using `tf.group()`, then run this group op. But why? TensorFlow is so much better now, you should use the new style.

Hope this helps, and welcome to StackOverflow (SO)!

**Edit**

If you want to copy a subset of the weights from one layer in model 1 to a new layer in model 2, then you can proceed like follows. In this example, I will only copy the weights and biases from the first 3 out of 5 neurons in layer 1:

In the code above, instead of:

```py
hidden2.set_weights(hidden1.get_weights())
```

Use this code:

```py
weights1, biases1 = hidden1.get_weights()
weights2, biases2 = hidden2.get_weights()
weights2[:, :3] = weights1[:, :3]
biases2[:3] = biases1[:3]
hidden2.set_weights([weights2, biases2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much MiniQuark for your detailed answer! I do, however, still not understand how the new Keras-style helps me restore subsets of weights in a fully connected layer. My only solution thus far is to simply copy the weights to the correct locations in the new graph by using an assign-operation. Any inputs on this?

Comment: My pleasure. What I showed is how to copy all the weights from one layer in model 1 to another layer in model 2, I did not copy all weights from all layers to the new model. When you call get_weights() on a layer, you get all of this layer's variables, say a1, a2, a3. If you only want to copy some of these weights to the new layer (say just a2), you need to get the weights from the new layer as well, say b1, b2, b3, then call set_weights([b1, a2, b3]). Hope this helps.